# How does Dynamo DB handle pagination

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I am using `Pagination` with the latest `DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient`.

I had a doubt as to how does the `DynamoDB` handle pagination? Is it that it queries `DDB` and gets back the result for the 1st page and then again hits DDB to fetch records for the 2nd fetch? Does it the DB as many times as the number of pages? I couldn't find any information related to this in AWS docs.

Comment: Is there an underlying question that you have, related to pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it hits the database for each page of data. There are limits of how much data DynamoDB will return in a single result, so it has to do it this way. The general mechanism for pagination in DynamoDB is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.Pagination.html).

Comment: Thanks Mark!! So if I want to send the result of one page of DDB as a json body to the requester and later only when he wants to see the next page i want to issue a query again to DDB. Is there any way in which i can keep track of which page was delivered and issue a query again only for the remaining pages?

Comment: Send the continuation token, preferably encoded, to the client with the list of items and have the client submit it back to you when asking for the next page. Or store it server-side in your session DB (if you have one).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think in java SDK 2 DDB uses continuation token anymore

Comment: @ghostrider it is absolutely using continuation token behind the scenes, because it is still going against the same DynamoDB API that everything else is. Also, I looked at `DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient` and I don't see a `query()` or `scan()` method, I only see a method to get up-to 25 items in a single transaction. What method are you currently calling? I'm not sure the Enhanced client is the one you need to be using for retrieving large paginated lists of records.

Comment: @MarkB It has a table() which returns a DynamoDBAsyncTable which has query(). I think we can use limit() in this case. Not exactly sure though

Comment: @ghostrider OK, so the `table()` method takes a `QueryEnhancedRequest` parameter, which has an `exclusiveStartKey()` attribute. And the response is a `PagePublisher` which in turn gives you one or more `Page` objects. The `Page` objects have the `lastEvaluatedKey` attribute. So that is how you would access and utilize those values using `DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient`.

Comment: @MarkB Yeah, but sadly the limit() of QueryEnhancedRequest is not working as expected and fetching all the records. Do you have any reference examples for the DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient for pagination? That would be of great help

Comment: I've never used `DynamoDBEnhancedAsyncClient` and I'm not an AWS employee, so no I don't have any extra documentation beyond what you have. Perhaps you need to show more of your code. That "Enhanced" class really does seem to be a higher level abstraction for use when you **don't** want to paginate through the results yourself. I still think you should be using the lower level client for the type of thing you are trying to do.